# How to undo any saved or previous file in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to undo the old project files that I got from my colleague to understand what was created first. Is it possible? Is there any tool for achieving this?

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Learn to use source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. That would only be possible if you colleague had been using a version control system (like Subversion, Mercurial, Git, TFS etc).